# Linux, forked process hangs immediately

Tags: c, linux, fork

I got a problem with fork that only occurs sporadically. It works basically all the time, but fails every once in a while on a test system.

My research didn't turn up anybody else mentioning a similar problem.

The problem occurs on an embedded Linux system. There is no swap partition available.

The process running has all signals blocked in all threads and handles them via sigtimedwait in a dedicated thread.

If I start a child process via fork:

- The parent process continues with a return value > 0. So the fork works. There is *no* -1 returned - so no error, not out of memory! The parent then waits on the child process and never returns from the wait.
- The child process never does anything *observable*. The very first thing the child process *should* do, is writing a log message. This log message never appears. Then it should spawn two child
  processes a time-out process and a worker process. These processes never appear.
- If I check via ps on the command line, I can see the existing child process. It is in the state *S* (Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)). It never gets any CPU time, it shows no CPU usage.
- If I *kill -9* the child process, the parent process finishes waiting and continues happily.

**Pseudo code showing the problem:**

```
const pid_t childPid = fork();
if(0 == childPid) {
    // child process
    LOG_MSG("Child process started."); // <- This never shows up in the syslog.

    // do some stuff

} else if(-1 == childPid) {
    // error
    LOG_MSG("Parent process: Error starting child process!");
    result = false;
} else {
    // parent process
    LOG_MSG("Parent process: Child process started. PID: %.", childPid); // <- This shows up in the syslog.

    // do some stuff
    int status = 0;
    const int options = 0;
    const auto waitResult = waitpid(childPid, &status, options);
    // more stuff
}
```

Questions:

1. What could cause this hanging child process?
2. What would happen, if the new process runs out of memory in the LOG_MSG call that leads to syslog? Would this raise a signal (that could no be delivered because it is blocked)?

Comment: The parent is process isn't waiting acutally

Comment: What is the definition of `LOG_MSG`?

Comment: Can you run your program with "strace", using the "-ff" option to follow forks? e.g. "strace -o output.txt -ff your_program". You should see a trace file for the parent process and any child it spawns. The information in these files may be illuminating.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I left the waitpid out, thinking mentioning it in the text, would be enough. I fixed the code sample to clarify what happens.

Comment: I think the `LOG_MSG` is the key here. I wouldn't be surprised if both parent and child would be competing for `LOG_MSG`s resources and this would be the problem.

Comment: @ PSkocik: LOG_MSG is a macro that calls a method on a logging class that writes to syslog after some scampering.

Comment: try attaching `gdb` to get a backtrace of the hung child process

Comment: Your problem is probably related to this : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=454183

Comment: @Jan: The parent is waiting and thus not competing for any resources. Also the code called by LOG_MSG is re-entrant as it is not using any external state and ends in a syslog call.
No proof but a good indicator: The logging system is used in a multi-threaded environment with 60+ threads - threads that are actually working (e.g. multiplexing video data). And it works fine and flawless for days at a time.

Comment: You said it was in an interruptible sleep, waiting for an event to complete. That looks like it is waiting on a lock (to the log file) and the parent is holding that lock.

Comment: Adrien's link suggests the problem may be related to an interaction between multithreading and fork. Mixing the two often causes problems. And you have a lot of threads. Perhaps you could start your child processes using "posix_spawn" instead of fork/exec? Or perhaps the child processes could just be threads? Either of these approaches would be safer than mixing threads and fork.

Comment: @Adrien Descamps: I am pretty sure that this is the problem. Thanks a lot! I will remove the syslog-ing and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: @PSkocik: This 'Interruptible sleep' state always shows up on idle processes. So I overlooked that that might mean waiting on an mutex or something like that. Thx for the input.

Comment: @Diego: When the code fails it runs as a release build on an embedded device in QA in an island subnet. We just get called there if the device hangs and there are no useful diagnostics (like a log). So it might be a little tricky to attach a remote debugger, but it is an good idea.

Comment: @Jack Whitham: Thanks for the hint with strace. I will keep that in mind for the future. Also: The child processes really need to be processes - it's not a gimmick. Threads won't do. And I use fork & exec as I need a timeout process to stop the spawned child if it hangs (the fork in the sample above is only creating the intermediate process that then forks the worker and the timeout process), and as I need to redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to a pipe. I don't know posix_spawn (yet), so I will have to check if it would suite my needs. But thx for the pointer.

Comment: @Jan: My comment above was apparently wrong. The code cannot be re-entrant if it is not async-signal-safe. And my code is _not_ async-signal-safe as it is (indirectly) calling syslog. So your initial thought was probably right. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the sample from [Adrien Descamps' link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=454183) (see also comments above) and C++-ified and modified it a little:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


std::atomic<bool> go(true);


void syslogBlaster() {
   int j = 0;
   while(go) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
         syslog(LOG_INFO, "syslogBlaster: %d@%d", i, j);
      }
      ++j;

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
   }
}

int main() {
   std::thread blaster(syslogBlaster);

   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      const auto forkResult = fork();
      if(0 == forkResult) {
          syslog(LOG_INFO, "Child process: '%d'.", static_cast<int>(getpid()));
          exit(0);
      } else if(forkResult < 0) {
         std::cout << "fork() failed!" << std::endl;
      } else {
         syslog(LOG_INFO, "Parent process.");
         std::cout << "Waiting #" << i << "!" << std::endl;
         int status = 0;
         const int options = 0;
         const auto waitResult = waitpid(forkResult, &status, options);
         if(-1 == waitResult) {
             std::cout << "waitpid() failed!";
         } else {
             std::cout << "Bye zombie #" << i << "!" << std::endl;
         }
      }

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(28));
   }

   go = false;
   blaster.join();

   std::cout << "Wow, we survived!" << std::endl;
}
```

Running this sample, the process gets stuck (on my device) between the first and the fifth try.

**Explanation**

syslog is the problem!

In general: ***non async-signal-safe functions*** are the problem!

As stated by Damian Pietras (see linked page)

> calling any function that is not async-safe (man 7 signal) in child
>   process after fork() call in a multi-threaded program has undefined
>   behaviour

Technically the problem (undefined behavior) arises from data in critical sections that is inconsistent (because a thread that is *not* the one forking was right in the middle of it during the fork) or - like in this case - from a mutex that was locked in the parent and then stays this way forever in the child.

Credit for this answer goes to Adrien Descamps for finding the root cause (syslog), but also to PSkocik and Jan Spurny for detecting the source (LOG_MSG).